# When looking for arbitrage among a LARGE amount of assets, is there an optimal way?

Tags: data, arbitrage, optimization

Looking for arbitrage opportunities when looking at 3 pairs of related currencies is easy. However if we assume that we have a large amount of currencies, is there an optimal way to swipe through them and checking the vast amount of different possible permutations? I haven't been able to find any research so far and the main problem is that I'm not entirely sure how to look for this.

Thank you

Comment: [Foreign Exchange Arbitrage](http://www.fatvat.co.uk/2010/07/foreign-exchange-arbitrage.html) (2010)

Comment: LOL: "running this code through the 21 million (!) ticker updates in January 2010 yields absolutely ZERO arbitrage opportunities."

Answer (score 10):

For example, [Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald Rivest, Clifford Stein. Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844), problem 24-3 says:

> *24-3 Arbitrage*
>
> *Arbitrage* is the use of discrepancies in currency exchange rates to transform one unit of a currency into more than one unit of the same currency. For example, suppose that 1 U.S. dollar buys 49 Indian rupees, 1 Indian rupee buys 2 Japanese yen, and 1 Japanese yen buys 0.0107 U.S. dollars. Then, by converting currencies, a trader can start with 1 U.S. dollar and buy 49 $\times$ 2 $\times$ 0.0107 = 1.0486 U.S. dollars, thus turning a profit of 4.86 percent.
>
> Suppose that we are given $n$ currencies $c_1, c_2, \ldots , c_n$ and an $n \times n$ table $R$ of exchange rates, such that one unit of currency $c_i$ buys $R[i, j]$ units of currency $c_j$.
>
> a. Give an efficient algorithm to determine whether or not there exists a sequence
> of currencies $<c_{i_1}, c_{i_2}, \ldots , c_{i_k}>$ such that
>
> $R[i_1, i_2] \cdot R[i_1, i_2] \cdots R[i_{k-1}, i_k] \cdot R[i_k, i_1]  > 1$
>
> Analyze the running time of your algorithm.
>
> b. Give an efficient algorithm to print out such a sequence if one exists. Analyze
> the running time of your algorithm.

*Selected Solutions* says:

> Solution to Problem 24-3
>
> a. We can use the **Bellman-Ford** algorithm on a suitable weighted, directed graph $G =(V,E)$, which we form as follows. There is one vertex in $V$ for each
> currency, and for each pair of currencies $c_i$ and $c_j$, there are directed edges $(v_i,v_j)$  and $(v_j,v_i)$. (Thus, $|V|= n$ and $|E|= n(n - 1)$.)
>
> To determine edge weights, we start by observing that
>
> $R[i_1, i_2] \cdot R[i_1, i_2] \cdots R[i_{k-1}, i_k] \cdot R[i_k, i_1]  > 1$
>
> if and only if
>
> $\dfrac{1}{R[i_1, i_2]} \cdot \dfrac{1}{R[i_1, i_2]} \cdots \dfrac{1}{R[i_{k-1}, i_k]} \cdot \dfrac{1}{R[i_k, i_1]}  < 1$.
>
> Taking logs of both sides of the inequality above, we express this condition as
>
> $\lg\dfrac{1}{R[i_1, i_2]} + \lg\dfrac{1}{R[i_1, i_2]} + \cdots +\lg\dfrac{1}{R[i_{k-1}, i_k]} +\lg \dfrac{1}{R[i_k, i_1]}  < 0$.
>
> Therefore, if we define the weight of edge $(v_i,v_j)$ as
>
> $w(v_i,v_j) = \lg \dfrac{1}{R[i, j]} = -\lg R[i, j]$.
>
> then we want to find whether there exists a negative-weight cycle in $G$ with
> these edge weights.
>
> We can determine whether there exists a negative-weight cycle in $G$ by adding
> an extra vertex $v_0$ with $0$-weight edges $(v_0, v_i)$ for all $v_i \in V$, running  **Bellman-Ford** from $v_0$, and using the boolean result of  **Bellman-Ford** (which is TRUE if there are no negative-weight cycles and FALSE if there is a negative-weight cycle) to guide our answer. That is, we invert the boolean result of **Bellman-Ford**.
>
> This method works because adding the new vertex 0 with 0-weight edges
> from 0 to all other vertices cannot introduce any new cycles, yet it ensures
> that all negative-weight cycles are reachable from $v_0$.
>
> It takes $\Theta(n^2)$ time to create $G$, which has $\Theta(n^2)$ edges. Then it takes $O(n^3)$ time to run **Bellman-Ford**. Thus, the total time is $O(n^3)$.
>
> Another way to determine whether a negative-weight cycle exists is to create $G$
> and, without adding $v_0$ and its incident edges, run either of the all-pairs shortest-paths algorithms. If the resulting shortest-path distance matrix has any negative values on the diagonal, then there is a negative-weight cycle.
>
> b. Assuming that we ran **Bellman-Ford** to solve part (a), we only need to find
> the vertices of a negative-weight cycle. We can do so as follows. First, relax
> all the edges once more *[pp 648ff]*. Since there is a negative-weight cycle, the $d$ value of
> some vertex $u$ will change. We just need to repeatedly follow the $\pi$ values until we get back to $u$. In other words, we can use the recursive method given by the PRINT-PATH procedure of Section 22.2, but stop it when it returns to vertex $u$.
>
> The running time is $O(n^3)$ to run **Bellman-Ford**, plus $O(n)$ to print the
> vertices of the cycle, for a total of $O(n^3)$ time.

Someone's sample code is in [github](https://gist.github.com/anilpai/dd00a9671c062390c848952eaddbbe1e). I am not sure if it's implemented correctly.

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282427

Related dicussion: https://www.thealgorists.com/Algo/ShortestPaths/Arbitrage

Related class notes on Bellman-Ford: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp20/cse101-a/Slides/Week-09/Lec-29.pdf

(I wonder if additional optimization is possible when the matrix is sparse because some currency pairs are not quoted. Also I wonder how people handle non-linear costs, e.g. fixed fees, or exchange rates that change depending on the size of the rate.)

Comment: Incredibly helpful, also really appreciate the extra links at the end, have a great day!

Comment: In practical applications, how would one then factor in trading fees and spread? In markets today, triangular (or polynomial) arbitrage opportunities are fleeting. A sure way to fill your order immediately would be to 'cross the spread', meaning you would always be buying at a higher price and selling at a lower price. Could these impacts be costed directly into the exchange rate itself?

Comment: This already doesn't assume that R[i,j]=R[j,i], i.e. can have bid-ask spread. I see no reason not to include in R other linear fees/spreads. But I wonder what people do about non-linear costs.

Comment: Non-linear costs, such as slippage?

Comment: [4th edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/026204630X)

Answer (score 3):

I feel this is not a duplicate of [a question asking about applications of graph theory](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/61189/848) as this goes the other way.

If you're talking purely about currency arbitrage, the quickest way seems to be finding a negative cycle in a graph of currency where the vertices are the currencies and the nodes the exchange rate.