# Arbitrage finding in the currencies markets

Tags: currency, cross-currency-basis

I was wondering whether anyone can improve on the following arbitrage finding scheme in the currencies market.

The following is modified from the book of Capinaki and Zastawniak called [Mathematics for Finance - An Introduction to Financial Engineering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0857290819)

pages 263, Solution 1.3:

"
I think a brief description of the general
method used to solve this and similar
problems would be in order here:

The general problem of finding arbitrage
opportunities exploiting n currencies
C_1, ..., C_n and m dealers
d_1, ..., d_m can be solved
as follows:

Construct a labelled directed graph G
having C_1, ..., C_n as nodes and
for each ordered pair (C_i,C_j) of
distinct currencies an arc from C_i to C_j
provided there exists at least one
dealer which can convert currency
C_i into currency C_j. Each such arc
is labelled with the ordered pair (d_ij, c_ij)
where d_ij is a dealer offering the best
exchange rate that converts one unit
of currency C_i into c_ij units of
currency C_j.

Next, for each directed cycle involving
from 2 to n distinct nodes of the
constructed currency digraph,
multiply together the numbers
c_ij appearing along the arc
labels of the cycle, keeping
track of the corresponding
dealers converting currency
currencies C_i into currencies C_j.
An arbitrage opportunity exists if
and only if one of these products
exceeds one.

In our example we have the graph
with labeled arcs:

USD --(A,0.9724)--> EUR
USD --(A,0.6311)--> GBP
EUR --(A,1.0202)--> USD
EUR --(B,0.6324)--> GBP
GBP --(A,1.5718)--> USD
GBP --(B,1.5623)--> EUR

Disregarding which vertex leads
and ends each cycle, we have
3 distinct cycles of length 2,
and 2 distinct cycles of length 3,
namely:

USD --> EUR --> USD
USD --> GBP --> USD
EUR --> GBP --> EUR
USD --> EUR --> GBP --> USD
USD --> GBP --> EUR --> USD

Only the last of these 5 cycles
reveals arbitrage opportunities,
which can be realized as follows:
"

[<-- here we can insert the solution
appearing on pages 263 and 264 -->]

Finally, at the end of this solution I would
suggest adding the following remark:

Note that the cycle producing the above
arbitrage could also be exploited starting
from any of the currencies appearing as
part of it. For instance, had we started
with GBP or EUR we could also have
exploited the following alternative
arbitrage opportunities:

GBP --> EUR --> USD --> GBP,
EUR --> USD --> GBP --> EUR.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When looking for arbitrage among a LARGE amount of assets, is there an optimal way?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/63308/when-looking-for-arbitrage-among-a-large-amount-of-assets-is-there-an-optimal-w)

Comment: The OP being a question of how to exploit latency in dealer quotes, is a lamentable pursuit.